# Convert Pandas Series/DF which has xml in each cell to form multiple columns?

Tags: python, xml, dataframe, series

I have a messy dataset which has parameters from an application contained in a single cell when read in a pandas series.
For instance,

```
parameters    
 |<data>|
     
 <parameters>|
      | <p num="1" value="0" />  |
    
   |<p num="2" value="0.0" />|
    
   |<p num="3" value="100.0" />| 
    
   |<p num="4" value="2" />|
  
   |<p/>|
     |...|
  
   ||...|
  
   |<data/>|
```

Then, it all is contained in a single cell of a dataframe and there are multiple cells with the same structure, whereas the only thing that change are the values.
I wanted to get those num"X" and transform each of them into a column in the data frame, where each of the cell will have the value of num"X" stored.

Is there a way you all can help me with that?
If more information is required, please, let me know.

Thank you

All my tries were unsuccessful; I tried converting each cell using element tree, but I think I just do not know how to go about it. My coding experience go as far as 8 days.

Comment: Looks like it is binary data and using standard libraries will not work.  You need to read the documentation and parse one field at a time.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure if it is truly a binary data. I am quite sure it is formatted as xml, but just happened to be trapped in a dataframe cell.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you have HTML/XML string inside the  cells in DataFrame. Here's short example how you can parse the data using `beautifulsoup`:

Suppose you have this dataframe:

```py
lst = [
    '<data><p num="11" value="0" /><p num="12" value="1" /><p num="13" value="1" /></data>',
    '<data><p num="21" value="2" /><p num="22" value="3" /><p num="23" value="4" /></data>',
]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': lst})
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                                                                 Column1
0  <data><p num="11" value="0" /><p num="12" value="1" /><p num="13" value="1" /></data>
1  <data><p num="21" value="2" /><p num="22" value="3" /><p num="23" value="4" /></data>
```

Then you can parse the data:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

df['Column1'] = df['Column1'].apply(lambda x: [(p['num'], p['value']) for p in BeautifulSoup(x, 'html.parser').find_all('p')])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                       Column1
0  [(11, 0), (12, 1), (13, 1)]
1  [(21, 2), (22, 3), (23, 4)]
```

Afterwards you can for example explode the dataframe and make new columns:

```py
df = df.explode('Column1')

df['Column1_num'] = df['Column1'].str[0]
df['Column1_val'] = df['Column1'].str[1]
```

Prints:

```
   Column1 Column1_num Column1_val
0  (11, 0)          11           0
0  (12, 1)          12           1
0  (13, 1)          13           1
1  (21, 2)          21           2
1  (22, 3)          22           3
1  (23, 4)          23           4
```

Comment: Hi Andrej, thank you for your answer. I have tried to do what you said and even though at the end new tables were created with data, they were NaN and I think it may be because of the xml branching being within three sub divisions, is there any way I can fix it?